# Is there a way to draw a radar chart with Altair in python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, radar-chart

I have been using the Altair python API for a Data Visualization project, and everything went smoothly until I wanted to add a radar chart to my app.

I could not find anything on Altair's python API documentation about radar charts, however there seems to be an entry about that in Altair's core documentation but I couldn't access it.

I saw that plotly had that feature but I would really have liked using only one plotting framework...

Is there really no way to make a radar chart with Altair in python ?

Comment: As far as I know, the altair is a javascript based [VEGA-Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/) graphing in python. VEGA has [radar charts](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/radar-chart/), but I don't think they can be realized in python.

Comment: This makes me very sad

Comment: I am not that experienced with `altair`, SO has developers looking at it, so let's wait for comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not implemented in VegaLite, you can see the discussion in these two issues and open a new one if you think there is a good case to be made for radar charts:

- https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3805
- https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/408

In Altair you might be able to hack something together by layering multiple `mark_arc` charts with a `fillOpacity=0` and a colored stroke (although I don't think this will work since I can't see any way to get right of the lines going towards the middle.